# find whether string is matched in many columns at once and return a matrix of logicals?

Tags: r, string, design-patterns, matching

Given a data structure like the following:

```
set.seed(10)
fruits <- c("apple", "orange", "pineapple")
fruits2 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, fruit1 = sample(fruits, 10, replace = T), fruit2 =   sample(fruits, 10, replace = T), fruit3 = sample(fruits, 10, replace = T))

> fruits2
   id    fruit1    fruit2    fruit3
1   1    orange    orange pineapple
2   2     apple    orange    orange
3   3    orange     apple pineapple
4   4 pineapple    orange    orange
5   5     apple    orange    orange
6   6     apple    orange pineapple
7   7     apple     apple pineapple
8   8     apple     apple     apple
9   9    orange    orange pineapple
10 10    orange pineapple    orange
```

I can easily test whether any location in the data.frame *is exactly equal to* a given string with `fruits2 == "mystring"` and it will return a very convenient format . For example:

```
fruits2 == "orange"
         id fruit1 fruit2 fruit3
 [1,] FALSE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
 [2,] FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
 [3,] FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
 [4,] FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
 [5,] FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
 [6,] FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
 [7,] FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
 [8,] FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
 [9,] FALSE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
[10,] FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
```

However, what I would really like to do is search for a pattern (e.g. "apple") and have the same format returned. That is, I would like to be able to test whether every item in the data.frame *contains (but is not necessarily equal to)* the string "apple" and have the same matrix of logicals returned. In this case, I would like it to produce:

```
         id fruit1 fruit2 fruit3
 [1,] FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
 [2,] FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
 [3,] FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
 [4,] FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
 [5,] FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
 [6,] FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
 [7,] FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
 [8,] FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
 [9,] FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
[10,] FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

Is there any easy way to do this in R without specifying multiple patterns (I know in this case `fruits2 == "apple" | fruits2 == "pineapple"`would do it, but in my real dataset enumerating all possible strings to exactly match is not possible)?

I figure there are workarounds and I could write a function to do it using `grepl()` but I am wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: My apologies for the code mistakes. Line 2 should read `fruits <- c("apple", "orange", "pineapple")` and line 3 is missing a close parentheses at the end of the call to `data.frame()`.

Answer (score 5):

In base R,

```
> apply(fruits2,2,function(x){grepl("apple",x)})
         id fruit1 fruit2 fruit3
 [1,] FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
 [2,] FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
 [3,] FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
 [4,] FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
 [5,] FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
 [6,] FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
 [7,] FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
 [8,] FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
 [9,] FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
[10,] FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE

 n = 10000
 fruits2 <- data.frame(id = 1:n, fruit1 = sample(fruits, n, replace = T), fruit2 =   sample(fruits, n, replace = T), fruit3 = sample(fruits, n, replace = T))

> system.time(apply(fruits2,2,function(x){grepl("apple",x)}))   
  user  system elapsed 
  0.016   0.000   0.019 

> system.time(colwise(myfun)(fruits2))
  user  system elapsed 
  0.016   0.000   0.017

> system.time(sapply(fruits2,function(x) grepl('apple',x)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.032   0.000   0.034
```

As @eddi points out, `lapply` is indeed the fastest:

```
> system.time(do.call("cbind",lapply(colnames(fruits2),function(x) grepl('apple',fruits2[,x]))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.016   0.000   0.016
```

Comment: I assume the `colwise` solution showed up as faster due to caching.  if you look at its code, it just calls `lapply` after some checks.

Comment: @Justin nah, `lapply` is just faster than `apply` here

Answer (score 3):

Dunno if you count this as simpler, but you can use `colwise` from the `plyr` package:

```
myfun <- function(x) grepl('apple', x)

colwise(myfun)(fruits2)

      id fruit1 fruit2 fruit3
1  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
2  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
3  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
4  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
5  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
6  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
7  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
8  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
9  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
10 FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

Comment: Seems very general as a strategy, since using a character vector argument (as I imagined the OP was requesting)  would also be possible if it were `paste`-ed with collapse="|".

Comment: `sapply(fruits2,function(x) grepl('apple',x))` is also roughly equivalent, I think.

Comment: I can't remember the example, but I coulda sworn I ran into instances where my data type would change using the `apply` family and was maintained using `colwise`...